# Provide escape support for custom characters in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to provide the ability to escape the { character in a string in PHP.

The string normally looks like so:

```
$route = '{controller}/{action}/{id}';
```

(Example result: Home/Index/3)

I would like to provide developers the ability to do the following:

```
$route = '{controller}/{action}/\{id\}={id}';
```

(Example result: Home/Index/{id}=3)

However, I would also like to provide support for if someone did the following:

```
$route = '{controller}/{action}/\\{id\\}';
```

(Example result: Home/Index/\3\)

I am aware of the addslashes and stripslashes functions but these don't provide the functionality I require.

I would also like to use this functionality in other areas of my code, so that I can keep the API consistent with the way in which PHP works.

First off, is this likely to cause clashes as if I use double quotes then I guess PHP would automatically escape the \\ to a \ and this is something I would need to account for as I want the returned result to be deterministic (ie the same, regardless of whether single or double quotes are used).

Secondly, if PHP already provides the ability to do this I would prefer a native implementation over custom code.

Lastly, if I have to resort to custom code what is the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please elaborate on usage context. Is this about a regex for front controller / dispatching? Or do you construct that string? (Then `add`**`c`**`slashes` is what you need.)

Comment: Shouldn’t the last rather be ```…/\\{id}\\```?

Comment: The usage will be across the framework, not specific to routing, but I've used routing as one example. The last example is correct either way, as the focus isn't on where the escaping will occur, the focus is how to support escaping with a backslash on characters other than the characters that PHP itself supports.

Comment: Well, what are you currently doing with these strings? Describing what you want to do without describing what you're _currently_ doing is simply a request for someone else to write code for you. It's implied you're using str_replace or preg_replace - it's not clear how.

Comment: Sounds like you pretty much want to create your own string parser. It's pretty trivial to implement with a state engine. Basically, look for any sort of parser implementation if you need a sample; e.g. a JSON decoder implemented in PHP.

Comment: Deceze, a string parser is indeed what I want, but I want one that works the way PHP's string parsing works, but using my own custom characters which will differ per usage.

Comment: AD7six, I'm doing neither, I'm looping through the string and looking for specific characters at the moment, I'm not asking for someone to write this functionality for me, I was hoping that PHP supported this functionality already as PHP itself has this functionality.

Comment: Sorry, but if a syntax like `{var}` get replaced by the corresponding variable value and ```\``` is used as an escape character, then I don’t see how ```\\{id\\}``` with `id=3` should result in ```\3\```. How does the `3` end up there if there is no `{id}` in it?

Comment: The code you've got **should be in the question**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind in regex to only match occurences of `{` and `}` without a `\` character in front of them.

The regex would be something like (note that you have to escape the slashes to `\\\\` in the actual PHP code)

```
(?<!\\\\)\{(.+?)(?<!\\\\)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Regex autopsy**:

- `(?<!\\)` - *A negative lookbehind specifying that the next match cannot have `\\` in front of it (an escaped `\` character)*
- `\{` - *A literal `{` character. Has to be escaped as `{` has actual meaning in regex*
- `(.+?)` - *A lazy matching group matching as little as possible (but with a minimum of 1 character) until it reaches the next match*
- `(?<!\\)` - *A negative lookbehind specifying that the next match cannot have `\\` in front of it (an escaped `\` character)*
- `\}` - *A literal `}` character. Has to be escaped as `{` has actual meaning in regex*

**Use in code**:

```
<?php

class Router {
    private $route;
    private $variables;

    public function __construct($route, $variables) {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->variables = $variables;
    }

    public function getRoute() {
        // Replace variables
        $route = preg_replace_callback('/(?<!\\\\)\{(.+?)(?<!\\\\)\}/', array($this, 'replaceRoute'), $this->route);

        // Replace escaped brackets and return it
        return str_replace(array('\{', '\}'), array('{', '}'), $route);
    }

    private function replaceRoute($match) {
        // Replace variable within {} if it exists
        return isset($this->variables[$match[1]]) ? $this->variables[$match[1]] : $match[0];
    }
}

$router = new Router('{controller}/{action}/\{id\}={id}', array(
    'controller' => 'Home',
    'action' => 'Index',
    'id' => 3
));

var_dump( $router->getRoute() ); // string(17) "Home/Index/{id}=3"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/180151)

Comment: I've changed the regex pattern slightly, as it is pretty much what I'm after, the regex pattern I have gone with is (?<!\\\\\)\{(.*)(?<!\\\\\)\} as there may not be any content between the { and }.

Comment: @Bonner Make sure you use `.*?` and not `.*`. `.*` is greedy and in `{controller}/{action}/{id}` it will match `controller}/{action}/{id` once, whereas `.*?` will match `controller`, `action` and `id`.

Comment: Cheers for that, will do.